# How do i exclude certain matches in optplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I have a requirement where I need to plan inside subset of data. For example, I have a stock of steel beams of certain grade. While planning I need to fit the available beams into stock only if they match the profile.

How do I do this with constraint streams. Any example would be appreciated.

I don't seem to get the hang around constraint streams.

I need to fit the ProjectMembers into StockMembers only if the profile matches.

Planning entity

```
@PlanningEntity
public class ProjectMember
    extends AbstractPersistable
    implements Labeled {

private int requiredLength; // in mm


private String profile;

public String getProfile() {
    return profile;
}

public void setProfile(String profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}

private StockMember stockMember;

ProjectMember() {
}

public ProjectMember(long id, int requiredLength) {
    super(id);
    this.requiredLength = requiredLength;
  
}

public int getRequiredLength() {
    return requiredLength;
}

public void setRequiredLength(int requiredLength) {
    this.requiredLength = requiredLength;
}


@PlanningVariable
public StockMember getStockMember() {
    return stockMember;
}

public void setStockMember(StockMember stockMember) {
    this.stockMember = stockMember;
}

@Override
public String getLabel() {
    return "Project Member " + id;
}

}


public class StockMember
    extends AbstractPersistable
    implements Labeled {

private int length; // in mm

private String profile;

private int cost; // in dollars

StockMember() {
}

public StockMember(long id, int length, int cost) {
    super(id);
    this.length = length;

    this.cost = cost;
}

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

public void setLength(int length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public void setProfile(String profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}
public String getProfile() {
    return this.profile;
}


@Override
@JsonIgnore
public String getLabel() {
    return "Stock Member " + id;
}

}
```

Planning solution

```
@PlanningSolution
public class NestMembers extends AbstractPersistable {

private List<StockMember> stockMemberList;

private List<ProjectMember> projectMemberList;

private HardSoftScore score;

NestMembers() {
}

public NestMembers(long id, List<StockMember> stockMemberList, 
List<ProjectMember> projectMemberList) {
    super(id);
    this.stockMemberList = stockMemberList;
    this.projectMemberList = projectMemberList;
}

@ValueRangeProvider
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
public List<StockMember> getStockMemberList() {
    return stockMemberList;
}

public void setStockMemberList(List<StockMember> computerList) {
    this.stockMemberList = computerList;
}

@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
public List<ProjectMember> getProjectMemberList() {
    return projectMemberList;
}

public void setProjectMemberList(List<ProjectMember> projectMemberList) 
{
    this.projectMemberList = projectMemberList;
}

@PlanningScore
public HardSoftScore getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(HardSoftScore score) {
    this.score = score;
}
```

Constraint Provider

```
public class NestingConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

@Override
public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory 
constraintFactory) {
    return new Constraint[]{
            matchProfile(constraintFactory),
            requiredLengthTotal(constraintFactory),

            memberCost(constraintFactory)
    };
}


Constraint requiredLengthTotal(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(ProjectMember.class)
            .groupBy(ProjectMember::getStockMember,
                    sum(ProjectMember::getRequiredLength))
            .filter((stockMember, requiredLength) -> requiredLength > 
stockMember.getLength())
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    (stockMember, requiredLength) -> requiredLength - 
stockMember.getLength())
            .asConstraint("requiredLength");
}

Constraint matchProfile(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(ProjectMember.class)
            .join(StockMember.class).
                    filter((projectMember, stockMember) -> 
!projectMember.getProfile().equals(stockMember.getProfile()))
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
            .asConstraint("requiredProfileMatch");


}


// 
 
 Constraint memberCost(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(StockMember.class)
            .ifExists(ProjectMember.class, equal(Function.identity(), 
ProjectMember::getStockMember))
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, StockMember::getCost)
            .asConstraint("cost");
}
```

Comment: How does your model look like so far? So planning enity class and planning variable field.

Comment: @PlanningEntity public class ProjectMemberd {

    private int requiredLength; // in mm

    private String profile;}

Comment: Surely your planning entity class has a planning variable?

Comment: Updated the question with the code I have done till now. Basically, I need to match profile of ProjectMember with StockMember. so only Members with matching profile needs to be fit into the stock, and should fit with length and least cost. The length and cost seems to be working fine but when profile is included as hard constraint everything goes for a toss. There is clearly something which I haven't understood yet. Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet. Sorry to bother you. Could you help out on this. I have put the code in comments. Thanks